# When to insert a comma when there are several ands in the sentence

Tags: commas, conjunctions

I apologize if this has already been answered somewhere, but I couldn't find it.

When there is a series of items or events in a sentence and they are connected by ands, do you need to insert a comma before each of the ands?

E.g. He went biking and sleighing and skating.

Additionally, what if the words are connected by or?

E.g. second or third or fourth.

Comment: See related threads, [_Using a comma in a sentence with multiple “and”s_](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94327/) and [_Sentence with multiple 'and's: should I use an Oxford comma, and if so, where?_](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60297/).

Comment: Thank you. I looked at both, and neither are quite what I was looking for. I also would have added a comma in the first thread you mentioned. However, I wouldn't add commas in either of the examples I gave. I'm trying to find out if I'm correct in that.

Comment: Also [Can I use *and* many times in one sentence?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/187868/can-i-use-and-many-times-in-one-sentence) -- you can, and it even has a rhetorical name.

Comment: I like the name it has and followed the link in the thread you gave. It appears to me that this is completely subjective. Some people use commas and some people don't. In the examples given in the link (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polysyndeton) Shakespeare used both ways. I thank you for the edification. I am now more knowledgeable today than I was yesterday. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since any answer that addresses the correct use of commas will likely be somewhat opinion-based, it is difficult to answer your question; however, I suggest that you purchase either the *Chicago Manual of Style* or the *Gregg Reference Manual,* and read their respective sections on the use of commas. For instance, both agree that a comma is required to set off a name in direct address; e. g., "Thank you, Jim."

As for your two examples, I agree with you that no commas are needed.